# I'm trying to use Stripe payment with my React-app and Node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments, production-environment

I'm a self-taught programmer with a lot to learn :)

I'm building a website for my first customer and I'm trying to implement the Stripe payment platform. I am building with React.js express and Node. I've been using this article for most of the setup: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/

On my test API, everything works absolutely perfect. I can see the test data with payments and everything. When I'm on the live website with the live API keys it doesn't create a charge. It posts the API call and has all the correct information but it doesn't charge the card.

Halfway down the article, he mentions PAYMENT_SERVER_URL which after all my digging I think might be the problem. I'm not 100% what he means by 'myapidomain'. When I'm not in production it's just my localhost:8080. I'm not sure what it would be on my production site.

I am hosting with HostGator if that helps. I've been trying to figure this out for about 3 days and am not sure where else to turn!

Frontend StripeComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import axios from 'axios'
import STRIPE_PUB_KEY from '../../../constants/stripePubKey'
import PAYMENT_SERVER_URL from '../../../constants/stripeServer'
import { clearReduxCart } from '../../../ducks/reducer'


const CURRENCY = 'usd';

const successPayment = (redirectHome, clearReduxCart) => {
  alert('Payment Successful');
  localStorage.clear()
  clearReduxCart()
  return redirectHome(true)
};

const errorPayment = data => {
  alert('Payment Error', data);
};

const onToken = (amount, description, email, redirectHome, clearReduxCart) => token =>
  axios.post(PAYMENT_SERVER_URL,
    {
      description,
      source: token.id,
      currency: CURRENCY,
      amount: amount,
      receipt_email: token.email
    })
    .then(successPayment(redirectHome, clearReduxCart))
    .catch(errorPayment);

const Checkout = ({ name, description, amount, email, redirectHome, clearReduxCart }) =>
  <StripeCheckout
    name={name}
    description={description}
    amount={amount}
    email={email}
    token={onToken(amount, description, email, redirectHome, clearReduxCart)}
    currency={CURRENCY}
    stripeKey={STRIPE_PUB_KEY}
    shippingAddress
    receipt_email
  />



export default Checkout
```

server/index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();



const express = require('express')
    , SERVER_CONFIGS = require('./const/server')
    , configureServer = require('./server')
    , configureRoutes = require('./routes')


const app = express();


app.use( express.static( `${__dirname}/../build` ) );



configureServer(app);
configureRoutes(app);

app.listen(SERVER_CONFIGS.PORT, error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(`Server running on port ${ SERVER_CONFIGS.PORT }` );
});
```

server/server.js

```
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const CORS_WHITELIST = require('./const/frontend');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) =>
    (CORS_WHITELIST.indexOf(origin) !== -1)
      ? callback(null, true)
      : callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
};

const configureServer = app => {
  app.use(cors());

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
};

module.exports = configureServer;
```

server/routes/payments.js

```
const stripe = require('../const/stripe');

const postStripeCharge = res => (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
  if (stripeErr) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: stripeErr });
  } else {    
    res.status(200).send({ success: stripeRes });
  }
}

const paymentApi = app => {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: 'Hello Stripe checkout server!', timestamp: new Date().toISOString() })
  });

  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: req.body.currency,
      source: req.body.source,
      description: req.body.description
    }, postStripeCharge(res));
  });

  return app;
};

module.exports = paymentApi;
```

Comment: A few things: 1) can you please post your server side code. 2) Have you removed React from the equation by calling your API with postman or curl? If not, try that and then post a copy of your curl command (or details of your postman call). Then you can reduce the problem to just your server side code. Make sure *not* to post any API keys! :)

Comment: Hi Elliot! Thank you for the quick response. I will edit my question and add the code right now. To be honest i've never heard of postman or Curl. However, I will definitely learn how if its going to help me as a web developer. Thank you!

Comment: Both just allow you to make a HTTP call to a service (locally running, or running on another server). If you post their details then we'll also be able to see the example data you're sending up and the format, it just ensures it's not something silly like the data you're sending to your API from React.

Comment: Postman is probably the most user friendly, but curl is best for posting questions to stackoverflow etc.

Comment: Okay yeah that totally makes sense! I'll have to do that cause the problem could be there. Thank you again for your input, I seriously appreciate it!

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn I believe this is all the code that is necessary. If there is more that would be beneficial, let me know. Thank you again!